# Strange findFn malfunction

Tags: r

I noticed a strange malfunction in using `findFn` function (library `sos`) and I can't find out the source. While it works fine on my Windows XP pc, it does not on my Vista one.

```
library (sos)

findFn("randomization test")
# in both finds 72 results

findFn("{randomization test}")
# In XP finds 19 or about so, but in Vista whenever I use {} and more than one word inside, 
# I keep getting the following:

found 0 matches
x has zero rows;  nothing to display.
Warning message:
In findFn("{randomization test}") :
  HIT not found in HTML;  processing one page only.
```

R ver = 2.10.1 and packages updated.
Any ideas where the problem might be?

Bonus: As it's obvious, I was looking for functions about `tests for randomized experiments`

Comment: Are you using the same R instance? And I mean *exact* the same, copied between two computers without change anything.

Comment: No, they are independent installations. And I can't recall if it was working at some earlier time, or it has never worked properly.

Comment: In unix (same R version) I get the same result you get in Vista

Comment: Stupid counter-question: why are you trying to use the curly brackets? It works fine without.

Comment: @Thrawn: Read the help file 
# To search for an exact string, use braces:
RSS. <- findFn('{RSiteSearch function}', 1)

Comment: Did you find why behaviour of `findFn` depends on OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the source code of the **sos** package, findFn.R, line 80, I found the mistake

```
  if (substr(string, 1, 1) != "{")
    string <- gsub(" ", "+", string)
```

This "if" is wrong, with an != instead of ==, and therefore the space doesn't get translated into a +. The quick solution would be to use the "+" syntax yourself

so:

```
> findFn("{randomization+test}")
found 19 matches
```

Comment: It would be great if you submitted this to the package authors.

Comment: Done, I emailed the author, and gave him this page's link. Hopefully we add another R programmer to the community of StackOverflow :-)